# JupyterHub: regular error message: "Your server at ... is not running. Would you like to restart it?"

Tags: server, jupyter, jupyterhub

We are running a JupyterHub server that is on an AWS-EC2 instance.

When we connect to the server we regularly (often after less then 10 minutes) have the error message `"Your server at ... is not running. Would you like to restart it?"`. The error appears while working from a notebook or even while just being in the terminal while a script is running.

Additional information:

- The EC2-Instance continues to work (it is possible to e.g. access it via a VNC-remote connection).
- We are accessing JupyterHub via Browser. The problem appears both via Firefox from Ubuntu 2004 and via Chrome from Windows 10.
- The operating system is `Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS`.
- The installed Jupiter-packages are:

.

```
pip freeze | grep jupyter

> jupyter-client==7.0.6
> jupyter-core==4.9.1
> jupyter-resource-usage==0.6.0
> jupyter-server==1.11.2
> jupyter-telemetry==0.1.0
> jupyterhub==1.5.0
> jupyterlab==3.2.2
> jupyterlab-pygments==0.1.2
> jupyterlab-server==2.8.2
> jupyterlab-widgets==1.0.2
> nteract-on-jupyter==2.1.3
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: I see this from time to time, especially when the internet connection is unstable. It does seem like jupyter is a bit quick to assume that the server isn't running when in fact the page could just use a refresh. Have you checked whether refreshing the page solves the problem?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado thanks for your advice. But the internet connection is extremely good and the error appears pretty exactly after 10 minutes of not working on it. Therefore I think there might be a timeout

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions:

**First solution - Quick and dirty and tested successfully:**
I realized that the error appeared when scripts have been running in the JupyterHub terminal. If JupiterHub is Jupiter focussed I opened a notebook and executed the following code:

```
from time import sleep
for i in range(24*60):
    print(f'server is running {i} minutes')
    sleep(60)
```

It seems like there is a timeout which is just ckecking Jupyter processes but not if scripts are running in the terminal.

**Second solution - the clean way to do it? - Not tested yet.**
I found a timeout described here:
https://tljh.jupyter.org/en/latest/topic/idle-culler.html

"By default, JupyterHub will ping the user notebook servers every 60s to check their status. Every server found to be idle for more than 10 minutes will be culled."

Parameter:

```
services.cull.timeout = 600
```

Comment: Oh! Yeah definitely do the latter. We’ve bumped these up to much larger values (eg 24h) for this reason. Sorry I didn’t realize your servers were actually shutting down - thought it was just an erroneous error message!

Comment: @MichaelDelgado thanks a lot for your inspiration! How exactly shall the 2nd solution be implemented? Via terminal or Settings? What is the command or steps to follow?

Comment: how did you deploy your jupyterhub? we use a helm chart and the value can be set there.